# Does a DMM resistance reading between lugs on an AFCI breaker indicate failure?

Tags: electrical

An AFCI breaker was removed from my load center.  While in service, the breaker would immediately trip when reset.  Out of the panel, when in the off position, the resistance between L1 and N lugs of the breaker is like 370 ohms.

Am I missing something, or is this clear cut internal failure of the breaker?  L1 was successfully being broken when the breaker tripped.

Comment: Do you have other AFCI breakers of the same type you could compare it to?  Having some resistance there is expected, because AFCI breakers have internal electronics to power.  Whether that's the right amount of resistance, I have no idea, but it doesn't strike me as an unreasonable number for a breaker to have.

Comment: The places there should *not* be any significant resistance is between the neutral lug and the neutral pigtail wire (or clip if it's a PoN), and between the hot lug and the bus clamp.

Comment: Good point, there are two others of the same make and model I can test for a "known" good.  The breaker in question was replaced with a new DF breaker that was high impedance across the lugs, and that did not trip, but that doesn't say much about what the expected reading should be for the old model.  38 watts for 370 ohms seems not wholly unreasonable (resistive load probably not a good assumption of the breaker smarts)

Comment: 38W would be pretty unreasonable actually, since a panel full of 40 of them would then be putting out over 1500W -- that's a space heater!  But it's definitely not a resistive load, so applying Ohm's law here won't give us any real info.

Comment: Tmband25  &   @nate s remember you are measuring with a dc device the meter.   An ac coil may have 13 ohms of resistance on your meter but only be a < 5 watt device because the impedance or the ac resistance value is almost 3k so dc resistance values may only be a clue.  Verification with a working breaker would be the only way to know for sure

Comment: @EdBeal, exactly, that's what I meant by "applying Ohm's law here won't give us any real info."

Comment: @nate s actually ohms law still works but frequency/ impedance is added for example a motor has a dc resistance of 5 ohms when the motor first is energized there is an incredible current spike until both the coils develop there impedance through a combination of coil strength and rotation. We can use ohms law to calculate the peak value then resonant factors and time where 3-5 time constants the coil will be fully energized and go from that 5 ohms to 1200 ohms for a small motor but the math still works it is a bit more complex.

Comment: @EdBeal, I know how it works; I'm an electrical engineer.  We can't use the frequency-adjusted version of Ohm's law here because we'd need to know the *impedance*, not just the *resistance* of the circuit, and I doubt OP has any easy way to measure that.  With a motor, that's probably in the datasheet, but not for a breaker.

Comment: @nate s the mag trip for breakers is normally a coil, but without knowing what the actual circuit is there is no way of knowing and that’s why I commented because dc values were being equated to heat.

Comment: @EdBeal, watts is heat; we just can't figure out the watts from the volts and ohms the way we could with DC or purely resistive AC circuits.

Comment: I think we all agree that the DC resistance reading is not necessarily the impedance.  Although @EdBeal I'm not sure it's a reasonable assumption that the mag trip coil is going to be across the line and neutral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC Resistance on load side of two same make-model breakers (QO120AFI) while also in tripped state was high, so the 370 ohm reading appears to be evidence of internal failure.

The breaker that failed was *not* in the recall date code range.

Glad this was checked before pulling new wire.

Comment: The chances of "pulling new wire" being the correct answer for an electrical problem are extremely low. Problems are *almost always* inside junction boxes, at terminations or loads.  The only way I would consider changing a cable is if two different AFCIs tripped while connected ONLY to that cable and no other cables or loads. But even then, I'd be skeptical.

Comment: Please be sure to click the check mark as soon as the system allows you to so others know this has a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know is verification with another working breaker.

Remember AC has impedance values that are much different than dc resistance.

When building relay isolation for PLC panels I have fun with apprentice’s having them calculate the load of the relays they rarely get it right for this very reason.

My guess is the breaker is toast but not for the wattage guessed at.